# Tracking individual users in Google Analytics for React application

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics

We have a react application with Google Analytics setup. In react, we have the following hook that we call in our App.js file.

**usePageTracking.js**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import ReactGA from 'react-ga';
import config from '../config';

const usePageTracking = () => {
    const location = useLocation();
    const [initialized, setInitialized] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!window.location.href.includes('localhost')) {
            ReactGA.initialize(config.gaTrackingId);
            setInitialized(true);
        }
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (initialized) {
            ReactGA.pageview(location.pathname + location.search);
        }
    }, [initialized, location]);

    return initialized;
};

export default usePageTracking;
```

**App.js**

```
...
let reactGAInitialized = usePageTracking();
...
if (reactGAInitialized) {
    ReactGA.set({ userId: userRes.data._id });
}
...
```

This initial setup seems to be working, as our Google Analytics page is tracking stuff. However, we are looking to get more granular information on individual users. First, is this individual-user tracking legal to do, in Google Analytics or in some other way? If so, then we'd like to see for each userId or email address:

- the time of their last session on our site (if they've ever logged in)
- number of sessions
- average session durations

Is this granular tracking of users possible in React, using Google Analytics or some other tool? Perhaps the info is already available in our Google Analytics dashboard and I am simply not aware of it? Or perhaps there is an addition to our code that will allow us to track users individually?

**EDIT:** We've discovered the `User Explorer` tab in Google Analytics, however we can not infer who is who from this tab. Is there a way in the code perhaps with `ReactGA.set()` to set an email address for the user to appear here? Or is this not allowed?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I could tell, Google Analytics doesn't collect / doesn't allow this type of PII (personally identifiable information). We ended up implementing an approach where we did our own custom logging. When a user (a) logs in, (b) changes pages, or (c) reaches our error page, it simply sends a document to our Mongo database with the users email address, the type of event, and time stamp. Simple but gets the job done for us.